# Installing tor in Ubuntu 18 Bionic: "No installation candidate"

Tags: tor

Hello can someone please help me with this problem? I tried to create tor.list according to torproject.org, but that did not work (unsigned etc..), so I removed it. I would expect that tor is installed from main ubuntu repository, it is listed in packages...

```
apt install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: It sounds like one of your actions messed something up.  In order to determine what that was, edit your question and include more complete reproducible details about all of the actions you have taken, especially whatever you are talking about with "tor.list" and exactly how you "removed it".

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) are different products to those using the more common *year.month* format (eg. 18.04). 18 != 18.04; it's been this way since 2016.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tor exists for 18.04 but not 18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: The guide how to enable universe repository suggests to use `add-apt-repository universe` but that is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

Add universe to your sources, and try `apt update` and `apt-cache search tor` See what packages are available. i'd try it, but I'm using Android right now. It should tell you the exact name of the tor package.

Comment: Tor has never been in main and that was never a Canonical decision.  Tor is an *anonymization* tool, regardless of if it's used by hackers or not, so those bits of your answers are irrelevant and likely to cause argument so I've removed those bits - please keep your answers to your *answers* and not include extra speculation where it's not needed